# How to overwrite my branch with contents from my colleague's branch?

Tags: git, merge, repository, branch

I am working with my colleagues with GIT as the source code repository.
Assume that he works on branch chris, I work on branch mike.
At some time, he merged **PART OF** the content from my branch mike to his branch chris.
I didn't do any changes on my branch mike anymore.
Later he did some more development.

Now, I'd like to keep my branch latest content (as chris). In other words, I'd like to overwrite all the content in mike with the content from chris.

How can I do the achieve this?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you should be able to do a fast-forward merge from chris to mike. For example:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout mike
git merge origin/chris
```

On the other hand, if you want to *delete* your "mike" branch and replace it with a copy of "chris," then you can do this:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout master
git branch -D mike
git checkout -b mike origin/chris
```

Make sure you have a solid backup before doing this sort of surgery on your repository, though. It's easier to restore a tarball or backup than to unwind a complex merge.

Comment: Pretty sure in that last command you meant `git checkout -b mike origin/chris`.

Comment: I take option 2, which is what I need. The 4th command will get the following message "fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'mike' which can not be resolved as commit?" Do you have any ideas? Thanks. Mike

Comment: @vergenzt Yes...not enough sleep, I guess. Thanks for catching the transposition!

Comment: @michael I had the branch names swapped; vergenzt was kind enough to point that out. Go ahead and give it another try with the update.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on branch "mike":

`git reset --hard chris`

Comment: As you've done nothing after he merges your code, you can do this.

Comment: This is clever, because it uses refs/heads/chris rather than an explicit commit hash. I think it's bound to confuse people who don't fully grok git internals--I prefer a more verbose syntax so that it's clear what the *intent* is--but I'm giving you kudos for the concise syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As simple as that.

1) Checkout your branch *mike*

`git checkout mike`

2) Merge your colleague's branch *chris*

`git merge chris`

There won't be any conflicts as your colleague have already merged your changes.

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: Yes, it shall be the simplest solution. However, I just found that there is something not merged by him, under his branch 'chris'. When I try the second command, it proposed the merge...